# Amazon S3 cli tool?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

Google Storage has a cli tool called gsutil for uploading and downloading files from Google Storage.

I wonder if Amazon S3 also has a such tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) is by far the best tool I've found for the job :). Works in most OS I had to use it on. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There is the [Amazon wrapper for curl](http://aws.amazon.com/code/128?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1), [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd), and [Bucket Commander](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--bucket-commander.html) among others.